# How to force delete an AWS ECR with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Using CloudFormation to delete a stack that contains an ECR with images results in a failure message:

```
The repository with name 'my-repo' in registry with id '123' cannot be deleted because it still contains images
```

The CLI provides a way of overriding this by using the `--force` flag:

```
aws ecr delete-repository --repository-name my-repo --force
```

How can I achieve the same result by solely using CloudFormation?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Because I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not, although I haven't looked since encountering it.

Comment: Having the same issue. I guess it could be solved by creating a lambda in your cloudformation that triggers on delete and removes the repository or cleans it up. But that's a bit of a hassle..

Comment: There's no way to do it with Cloudformation. Same "problem" with S3 buckets. I think it's there as a safety check, and you have to empty the resource outside CF before you can delete it with CF.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/224

Comment: Research is still under progress it seems: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/515

Comment: You can use a custom resource to do it

Answer (score 1):

Force deletion is now (22/08/2023) available as per [this comment](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/515#issuecomment-1688905707):

> ECR Repository resource now includes the EmptyOnDelete property to support force delete of repositories.
> If true, deleting the repository force deletes the contents of the repository. If false, the repository must be empty before attempting to delete it.

> Please see public docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Force deletion of an ECR repository is currently not available. There is, in fact, an open [issue](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/515) requesting this feature.

As a workaround, you may deploy a [lambda-backed custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) that empties the ECR repository on stack deletion.

> When you associate a Lambda function with a custom resource, the function is invoked whenever the custom resource is created, updated, or deleted. AWS CloudFormation calls a Lambda API to invoke the function and to pass all the request data (such as the request type and resource properties) to the function.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```json
{
    "Parameters": {
        "ECRRepositoryName": {
            "Description": "Name of ECR repository",
            "Default": "test-repository",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "ECRRepository": {
            "Type": "AWS::ECR::Repository",
            "Properties": {
                "RepositoryName": {
                    "Ref": "ECRRepositoryName"
                }
            }
        },
        "LambdaEmptyECRRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            },
                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [
                    {
                        "PolicyName": "ecr-access-policy",
                        "PolicyDocument": {
                            "Version": "2012-10-17",
                            "Statement": [
                                {
                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                    "Action": [
                                        "ecr:*"
                                    ],
                                    "Resource": "*"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "LambdaEmptyECR": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "DependsOn": "ECRRepository",
            "Properties": {
                "Code": {
                    "ZipFile": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "\n",
                            [
                                "import os",
                                "import cfnresponse",
                                "import boto3",
                                "",
                                "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
                                "    response = {}",
                                "    if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':",
                                "        region = event['ResourceProperties']['Region']",
                                "        repository_name = event['ResourceProperties']['ECRRepositoryName']",
                                "        client = boto3.client('ecr', region_name=region)",
                                "        images = client.list_images(repositoryName=repository_name)",
                                "        image_ids = [image for image in images['imageIds']]",
                                "        try:",
                                "            client.batch_delete_image(repositoryName=repository_name, imageIds=image_ids)",
                                "            while client.list_images(repositoryName=repository_name)['imageIds'] != []:",
                                "                os.sleep(1) # wait for images to be deleted",
                                "            response['output'] = 'Successfully deleted images in ECR repository'",
                                "            cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response)",
                                "        except Exception as e:",
                                "            response['output'] = 'Error'+ e.__str__()",
                                "            cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.FAILED, response)",
                                "    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response)"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
                "Role": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaEmptyECRRole",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Runtime": "python3.8"
            }
        },
        "EmptyECR": {
            "Type": "Custom::LambdaDependency",
            "DependsOn": "ECRRepository",
            "Properties": {
                "ServiceToken": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaEmptyECR",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "ECRRepositoryName": {
                    "Ref": "ECRRepositoryName"
                },
                "Region": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on stack deletion, the lambda function is invoked prior to the deletion of the ECR repository and deletes all images contained in the repository.

For more information on custom resources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

---

To try out this example:

1. Deploy the CloudFormation template
2. Push any image to the ECR repository
3. Delete the CloudFormation template