# Delete AWS Cloud formation stack with the resources it tries to retain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am currently facing an obstacle where I have a flow where I from a cross account are able to Delete a stack on another account using [CodePipeLine](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-codepipeline-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/action-reference-CloudFormation.md)

The execution of deletion works but at some point it fails to deletes the stack due to the: DELETE_FAILED

This is because the stack has an ECR which contains an image. And I would like to delete the image as well as the ECR But I just can't find a way to do this... I've really tried to find a solution but with no luck. It would be great to have a way of "Forcing the deletion" somehow.

```
The Error I recieve in the DELETE_FAILED action:
"The repository with name 'x' in registry with id '111199999' cannot be deleted because it still contains images.
```

Not sure if this alternative work around would work and I also find it a bit more complicated than what it should be but:

1. Invoke a lambda function on the cross account to delete the ECR & its image
2. Delete the stack after this.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76184754/3390419

Comment: Hello Thanks, I've managed to delete the ECR image within the same Account But when I try to do it on the cross account I recieve:
"Cross-account pass role is not allowed.
I have a trust relationship and assuming the right policies on that execution role the Lambda is using but I recieve this error. I tried to read on this error message but it gets me on a dead end.... can't find the solution for this.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please upvote it. This way we can close this question as a duplicate, and then you can ask a new question about the cross account issue since it's a separate thing